# NU1608 Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

In the solution that I have to work with, I have to add a test harness for a number of library projects.
It has to be a .NET Core 2.1 (and it will stay this way for the reasons beyond my control) ASP.NET web service.

> NU1608    Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but version Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.2.0 was resolved.

I created a brand new project of the type "Asp Net Core Web Application", and when I built, I got the error above.
What is the meaning and reason of this error in a brand-new project created by VS?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this issue, because while your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design` version is 2.2.0 but `ASP.NET Core application` is still at 2.1.

You just need to change your package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design2.2.0` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design2.1.x` in your project file.

Comment: I am always ticked off by "your" in these answers, because none of this is "mine". Visual Studio created the project this way. Why is it using incompatible libraries?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue** described in Microsoft documentation as NuGet Warning [**NU1608**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1608):

> A resolved package is higher than a dependency constraint allows. This
> means that a package referenced directly by a project overrides
> dependency constraints from other packages.

**Possible solution:**

Update the package version according to its dependency constraints.

*For example in this case:*

Update `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.2.0` to `2.1.x` according to its dependency `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1`

[image]